# How can I see only phone contacts, not SIM contacts?

Tags: contacts, sms, sim-card, zte-blade

I have a Dell XCD35.

My phone book was showing phone contacts as well as SIM contacts.

So when I see the list it shows some contacts twice. I don't want that, so in `display option` of contacts I just unchecked SIM contacts, which solves the problem in the Contacts app.

But I face the same problem when I am composing a SMS message. When searching for contacts it shows both Phone and SIM contacts.

Is there any way to disable SIM Contacts everywhere?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved this by erasing all contacts on the SIM. Here's how:

1. Contacts app -> Menu -> View. Uncheck all but SIM, press OK.
2. Menu -> Delete.
3. Menu -> Select All.
4. Press Delete.

After a while all SIM contacts are gone. Now re-enable showing the Phone and/or Google contacts and you're good to go!

(My phone uses Swedish so maybe the menu items/buttons above have other similar names)

Answer (score 4):

Go to contacts -> press menu button and choose more -> then display options -> there you can choose either SIM or Phone. And say DONE

Comment: this will work only for contacts but when you go for compose message at that time it will show both phone and SIM contacts.

Answer (score 2):

Try this [SIM Contacts Manager](https://market.android.com/details?id=ice.andrea.contactmanager) application from Android Market. It is going to manage all your contacts which are in SIM card.

There is one more possibility of having duplicates in your contacts list. If you are importing/synchronizing the Contacts from Facebook/Gmail/Twitter then it will show the contacts twice or more. In this case use this [Contacts Merger](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.beavercreekconsulting.contactscleaner) which merges the duplicate contacts.

Comment: @Mihir: Please search in the Android market. If there is any free app is available. If I find I will share that with you.

Comment: Try this app. This does duplicate contacts merging job. https://market.android.com/details?id=com.jbapps.contact

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps anyone:

The above instructions did not work for me,
on my Sony Xperia L15, Android 2.3.3

I think this is because of my ancient Android OS. :-)

I manually see which contacts are phone-only, by:

- Open contacts
- Menu
- Delete contacts

The Delete window has a little status line beside each contact, to tell you where the contact is stored:

- Google
- Phone contact
- Joined contact (think this means the contact was originally 2 or more contacts)

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is does not seem to be an answer to the Original Poster's question. This seems to be a comment for someone's answer instead. But useful information, nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

Some old phones have options hidden in the "square" button of the phone i.e. there's no "..." button in the app, you have to press the "square" button of your phone